# Exec python from php

Tags: php, python

I'm trying to run a python script from php with

```
$res = '';
exec('./home/Desktop/Scripts/fetch_matches.py', $res);
```

My python file starts with `#!/usr/bin/python` and has exec rights. For now I only have a print in there but it's not working(`var_dump($res)` gets me an empty array). What's missing?

Also, if I'll have different methods in that script, how would I call them?

Comment: Correct relative path? Have you enabled error_reporting?

Comment: *My python file starts with #!/usr/bin/python and has exec rights* exec rights for **???*** and second to check is the php user/group able to go in the home directory?

Comment: Yes, that's the path `pwd` gives me and I think it's enabled since I got errors for other parts of the program

Comment: can you execute it from `terminal` ? That `PY` file? I mean direct execution?

Comment: yes, I can execute it from terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get rid of the `.` before the path. If it's a normal Unix/Linux system, `/home` is in the root of the filesystem. `.` means the current directory, so unless you've recreated the `/home` filesystem in the directory from which you're running the PHP program, the path is incorrect. Also, unless your username is `Desktop`, you're missing a directory between `/home/` and `Desktop/` - it should be your username. The `pwd` command will never return a `.` before the present working directory.

For your second question, please refer to the docs on [calling Python from the command line](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html). You can execute arbitrary code from the command line, which could be something along the lines of

```
python -c "from fetch_matches import Fetcher; Fetcher()"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change your exec to include `/usr/bin/python` this should work as expected:

```
exec('/usr/bin/python ./home/Desktop/Scripts/fetch_matches.py', $res);
```

In these circumstances you should probably use absolute paths (check [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) as well as [chdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) and any argument escaping you need to do).

I'm not completely familiar with how the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) in files is run but I know if calling from PHP it's far better just to include the interpreter in the command you run.